# Usando os ícones do Font awesome no Woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theme, woocommerce

Como usar os ícones do [Font Awesome](http://fontawesome.io/icons/) nas páginas do woocommerce?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que dessa forma vai funciona, vai no functions.php e acrescenta esse código.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_load_fa' );
function enqueue_load_fa() {

    wp_enqueue_style( 'load-fa', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css' );

}
```

Agora basta acrescentar os ícones pelo editor de texto, tipo assim

```
<i class="fa fa-home fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

***Fonte:*** https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/font-awesome-wordpress

> **Documentação Oficial do Woocomerce** sobre Font-Awesome
>
> https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/using-icon-fonts/

Lista de ícones: http://fontawesome.io/icons/